# Form response calculation

Tags: javascript

I just create a form and table for a physical therapist. Need your help in calculating "sum based on response". The extreme difficulty value can be "0" and no difficulty can be "4"

I am familiar with reading and modifying js, html, css code. Here is what I wrote.

```html
<FORM >
  <TABLE BORDER>
    <TR ALIGN=CENTER>
      <TD WIDTH=350><B>ACTIVITIES<B> </TD>
      <TD WIDTH=125><B>Extreme difficulty (0)</B></TD>
      <TD WIDTH=125><B>Quite a bit of difficulty (1)</B></TD>
      <TD WIDTH=125><B>Moderate Difficulty(2)</B></TD>
      <TD WIDTH=125><B>Little Difficulty(3)</B></TD>
      <TD WIDTH=125><B>No Difficulty(4)</B></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR ALIGN=CENTER>
      <TD  ALIGN=LEFT> Any of usual work (household, work)</TD>
      <TD><INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="stimulat" VALUE="1"></TD>
      <TD><INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="stimulat" VALUE="2"></TD>
      <TD><INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="stimulat" VALUE="3"></TD>
      <TD><INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="stimulat" VALUE="4"></TD>
      <TD><INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="stimulat" VALUE="5"></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR ALIGN=CENTER>
      <TD  ALIGN=LEFT> Your hobbies, recreational, sporting</TD>
      <TD><INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="freedom" VALUE="1"></TD>
      <TD><INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="freedom" VALUE="2"></TD>
      <TD><INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="freedom" VALUE="3"></TD>
      <TD><INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="freedom" VALUE="4"></TD>
      <TD><INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="freedom" VALUE="5"></TD>
    </TR>    
    <TR ALIGN=CENTER>
      <TD  ALIGN=LEFT> Lifting bag of groceries to waist level</TD>
      <TD><INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="demand" VALUE="1"></TD>
      <TD><INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="demand" VALUE="2"></TD>
      <TD><INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="demand" VALUE="3"></TD>
      <TD><INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="demand" VALUE="4"></TD>
      <TD><INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="demand" VALUE="5"></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR ALIGN=CENTER>
      <TD  ALIGN=LEFT> Grooming your hair</TD>
      <TD><INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="creative" VALUE="1"></TD>
      <TD><INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="creative" VALUE="2"></TD>
      <TD><INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="creative" VALUE="3"></TD>
      <TD><INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="creative" VALUE="4"></TD>
      <TD><INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="creative" VALUE="5"></TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
</FORM>
```

I do not know how to calculate the result value to this form

Comment: Is this all? There's probably more to it to get the answer

Comment: The purpose is to have a about five questions with five choices each. The left most selection will carry a value of zero then 1, 2, 3,4. When a patient makes selection for all five questions, then the form should evaluate his choices and print Total at the bottom. As example if he picks middle for all his choices, then total is 10. Don't know how to do that. Thanks so much for your help

Comment: If there's a form that is readily available. I can use that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New and complete solution

```js
const
  theForm        = document.querySelector('#the-Form'),
  theTabBody     = document.querySelector('#Activities-Table tbody'),
  theTotal       = document.querySelector('#the-Sum'),
  theReset       = document.querySelector('#the-Reset'),
  PrintButton    = document.querySelector('#bt-Print'),
  ActivitiesList = [
    { name: 'household', lib: 'Any of usual work, household, or school activities' }
  , { name: 'hobbies',   lib: 'Your usual hobbies, recreational, sporting activities' }
  , { name: 'groceryw',  lib: 'Lifting bag of groceries to waist level' }
  , { name: 'groceryd',  lib: 'Lifting a bag of groceries above your head' }
  , { name: 'grooming',  lib: 'Grooming your hair' }
  , { name: 'pushing',   lib: 'Pushing up on your hands (e.g. from bathtub or chair)' }
  , { name: 'food',      lib: 'Preparing food (e.g. peeling, cutting ..)' }
  , { name: 'driving',   lib: 'Driving' }
  , { name: 'cleaning',  lib: 'Vaccuming, sweeping, or raking ' }
  , { name: 'dressing',  lib: 'Dressing' }
  , { name: 'dbuttons',  lib: 'Doing up buttons' }
  , { name: 'appliance', lib: 'Using tools or appliances' }
  , { name: 'doors',     lib: 'Opening doors' }
  , { name: 'cleaning1', lib: 'Cleaning' }
  , { name: 'shoes',     lib: 'Tying or lacing shoes' }
  , { name: 'sleep',     lib: 'Sleeping' }
  , { name: 'laundry',   lib: 'Laundering cloths (e.g. washing, ironing, folding)' }
  , { name: 'jar',       lib: 'Opening a jar' }
  , { name: 'ball',      lib: 'Throwing a ball' }
  , { name: 'carrying',  lib: 'Carrying a small suitcase with affected limb' }
  ]
;

function CaculSum()
{
  let total = 0;

  ActivitiesList.forEach( line => {
    total += parseInt(document.querySelector(`input[name="${line.name}"]:checked`).value);
  })
  theTotal.textContent = ` total = ${total} `;
}

function GlobalInit()
{
  let Cheking = '';
    
  ActivitiesList.forEach( (line,iLine) => {
    let
      newRow  = theTabBody.insertRow(-1),
      newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);

      newCell.textContent = line.lib;

      Cheking = 'checked';

      for (let i=0; i<5; i++) {
        newCell           = newRow.insertCell(i+1); // id="R-${iLine}-${i}"
        newCell.innerHTML = `<input type="radio" name="${line.name}" id="R-${iLine}-${i}" value="${i}" ${Cheking}>`
        newCell.innerHTML += `<label for="R-${iLine}-${i}">&#x2610;</label>`; // not checked
        newCell.innerHTML += `<label for="R-${iLine}-${i}">&#x2611;</label>`; // checked
        newCell.innerHTML += `<label for="R-${iLine}-${i}">&#x2714;</label>`; // print checked

        Cheking = '';
      }
  })
  theTotal.textContent = ' total = 0 ';
}

GlobalInit();

theForm.onchange = CaculSum;

theForm.onreset = function() { 
  theTotal.textContent = ` total = 0 `;
};

PrintButton.onclick = function(){
  window.print();
}
```

```css
body {
  font :16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h3 {
  text-align:center;
  color:blue;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 10px 20px;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
}

tr td:first-child {
  text-align: left;
  min-width: 350px;
  max-width: 350px;
}

thead td {
  font-weight: bold;
  background: lavender
}

#the-Sum {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 20px;
  padding: 10px;

  font-weight: bold;
  color: crimson;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 350px;

}
tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: lavender
}

#the-Form > label, 
#the-Form > input {
  background-color:lavender;
  color: black;
  margin: 5px 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: bold
}
#the-Form > input {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width : 300px;
}

#the-Form tbody label { font-size: 22px; }

input[type=radio] { display:none }
input[type=radio] + label { display:inline; color: grey; } 
input[type=radio] + label + label { display:none; color:black; } 
input[type=radio]:checked + label { display:none } 
input[type=radio]:checked + label + label { display:inline } 
input[type=radio] + label + label + label { display:none }
```

```html
<style media="print">
    h3, output {  color: black; }
    h4, button { display: none; }
    table { margin: 10px 0; }
    tr td:first-child { min-width: 400px; max-width: 400px; }
    tbody tr:nth-child(even) { background: none }
    #the-Form tbody label { display:none  }
    input[type=radio]:checked + label + label + label { display:inline !important }
</style>

<h3> Dr ABC<br> MYLocation</h3>

<h4> We are interested in knowing wheather you are having any difficulty with the 
    activities listed below <u> because of your upper limb problem </u>
    for which  you are seeking attention. <br>Provide an answer for each activity
    Today, <u>do you or would you </u> have any difficulty with: (check boxes below 
    on each line)
</h4>

<form id="the-Form">
  <label for="patientName"> Enter Patient's Name :</label>
  <input type="text" id="patientName" value="" />
    
  <table id="Activities-Table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>ACTIVITIES </td>
        <td>Extreme difficulty&nbsp;(0)</td>
        <td>Quite a bit of difficulty&nbsp;(1)</td>
        <td>Moderate Difficulty&nbsp;(2)</td>
        <td>Little Difficulty&nbsp;(3)</td>
        <td>No Difficulty&nbsp;(4)</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
  </table>

  <output id="the-Sum"></output>
  <!-- <button type="submit">submit</button> --> 
  <button type="reset">reset</button>
  <button id="bt-Print">Print or Save as pdf</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, It fits perfectly. You are very smart. I am trying now to add a couple of buttons for the ability to save the document and send via email. If it won't take too long, and you have few minutes, please help me there as well. Thank you so much

Comment: Cannot find location to accept the answer. Your solution worked well

Comment: `@user3877540`
I saw that you gave an answer with more information, so I changed my answer by integrating this, I also simplified the mode of filling the table and adapted the CSS style so that the impression is more clear.
I'm glad that my solution helps you, but I'll be really happy if you validate my answer.
This is the type of return that any respondent is waiting for here, please do not disappoint them.
 https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

```
<h4 style="text-align:center;color:blue;"> Dr ABC<br> MYLocation</h4>

<form action="" method="get">
    <b> Enter Patient's Name :</b> <input type="text"  /><br>
</form>
<h4> We are interested in knowing wheather you are having any difficulty with the 
 activities listed below <u> because of your upper limb problem </u>
for which <br> you are seeking attention. Provide an answer for each activity</h4>
<h4> Today, <u>do you or would you </u> have any difficulty with: (check boxes below 
on each line)</h4>
<style>table, td { border: 1px solid grey }
    td {
      text-align: center;
      min-width: 125px;
      max-width: 125px;
    }
    tr td:first-child {
      text-align: left;
      min-width: 350px;
      max-width: 350px;
    }
    thead td { font-weight: bold }
    #the-Sum {
      display: block;
      margin: 10px 0 0 20px;
      font-weight: bold;
      color:crimson;
}</style>
<form id="the-Form">
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td>ACTIVITIES </td>
    <td>Extreme Difficulty or Unable to Perform Activity&nbsp;(0)</td>
    <td>Quite a Bit of Difficulty&nbsp;(1)</td>
    <td>Moderate Difficulty&nbsp;(2)</td>
    <td>A Little bit of Difficulty&nbsp;(3)</td>
    <td>No Difficulty&nbsp;(4)</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td> Any of usual work, household, or school activities</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="household" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="household" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="household" value="2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="household" value="3"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="household" value="4"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Your usual hobbies, recreational, sporting activities</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="hobbies" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="hobbies" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="hobbies" value="2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="hobbies" value="3"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="hobbies" value="4"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Lifting bag of groceries to waist level</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="groceryw" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="groceryw" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="groceryw" value="2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="groceryw" value="3"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="groceryw" value="4"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Lifting a bag of groceries above your head </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="groceryd" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="groceryd" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="groceryd" value="2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="groceryd" value="3"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="groceryd" value="4"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> Grooming your hair </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="grooming" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="grooming" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="grooming" value="2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="grooming" value="3"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="grooming" value="4"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Pushing up on your hands (e.g. from bathtub or chair) </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="pushing" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="pushing" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="pushing" value="2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="pushing" value="3"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="pushing" value="4"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Preparing food (e.g. peeling, cutting </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="food" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="food" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="food" value="2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="food" value="3"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="food" value="4"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Driving </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="driving" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="driving" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="driving" value="2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="driving" value="3"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="driving" value="4"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Vaccuming, sweeping, or raking </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="cleaning" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="cleaning" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="cleaning" value="2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="cleaning" value="3"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="cleaning" value="4"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Dressing </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="dressing" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="dressing" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="dressing" value="2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="dressing" value="3"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="dressing" value="4"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Doing up buttons </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="dbuttons" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="dbuttons" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="dbuttons" value="2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="dbuttons" value="3"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="dbuttons" value="4"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Using tools or appliances</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="appliance" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="appliance" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="appliance" value="2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="appliance" value="3"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="appliance" value="4"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Opening doors </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="doors" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="doors" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="doors" value="2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="doors" value="3"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="doors" value="4"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Cleaning </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="cleaning1" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="cleaning1" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="cleaning1" value="2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="cleaning1" value="3"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="cleaning1" value="4"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Tying or lacing shoes</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="shoes" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="shoes" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="shoes" value="2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="shoes" value="3"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="shoes" value="4"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Sleeping</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="sleep" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="sleep" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="sleep" value="2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="sleep" value="3"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="sleep" value="4"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Laundering cloths (e.g. washing, ironing, folding)</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="laundry" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="laundry" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="laundry" value="2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="laundry" value="3"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="laundry" value="4"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Opening a jar</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="jar" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="jar" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="jar" value="2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="jar" value="3"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="jar" value="4"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Throwing a ball </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="ball" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="ball" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="ball" value="2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="ball" value="3"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="ball" value="4"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Carrying a small suitcase with affected limb </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="carrying" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="carrying" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="carrying" value="2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="carrying" value="3"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="carrying" value="4"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<output id="the-Sum"> total = 0 </output>
</form>
<script>
    const
  theForm         = document.querySelector('#the-Form'),
  theTotal        = document.querySelector('#the-Sum'),
  List_RadioGroup = [ 'household', 'hobbies', 'groceryw', 'groceryd', 'grooming', 'pushing', 'food', 'driving', 'cleaning', 'dressing', 'dbuttons', 'appliance', 'doors', 'cleaning1', 'shoes', 'sleep', 'laundry', 'jar', 'ball', 'carrying']
  ;

// load init.
theTotal.textContent = ' total = 0 ';
List_RadioGroup.forEach(xElm=>{ theForm[xElm][0].checked = true; })


theForm.onchange = function()
{
  let total = 0;
  List_RadioGroup.forEach(xElm=>{
    total += parseInt( document.querySelector(`input[name="${xElm}"]:checked`).value );
  })
  theTotal.textContent = ` TOTAL OUT OF 80 = ${total} `;
}
</script>
<div><form>
<input type="button" value="Print or Save as pdf" onClick="window.print()">
</form></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var total = 0;
var hi = getelementById("hi");

hi.onclick = function(){
total = 0;
}
```

Try adding id's to all of your check boxes and add an onclick function to them that adds up the total

https://jsfiddle.net/Lvejzuac/

Comment: Can you please provide a sample for any one. Didn't understand how to do it